# Why mmap flag reduces memory consumption for single Word2Vec instance

Tags: ram, gensim, mmap, word2vec

According to the docs and wikipedia:

mmap allows processes to share same chunk of ram

```
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load(config.get(wv_file))
```

This model loaded like this takes ~2.2 GB ram

```
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load(config.get(wv_file), mmap='r')
```

This model loaded like this takes ~1.2 GB ram

Why am I observing such drastic decrease in ram consumption?

Loading multiple models simultaneously, works as expected and models share the ~1 GM memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory-mapping re-uses the operating system's virtual-memory functionality to use the existing file as the backing-source for a range of addressable memory.

With a single process, it *won't* necessarily save any memory. Instead, it just:

- *Delays* loading any range-of-the-addresses into RAM, leaving it on disk until requested. If it's never requested, then RAM is never used, so in that particular case it may "save" memory.
- *Allows* those loaded ranges to be cheaply discarded if they're not accessed for a while, and the RAM is required for other allocations – because those ranges can be reloaded on demand from disk if ever again needed. So it might "save" memory in that case, compared to exhausting RAM or activating other generic virtual-memory that's not aware of the 1:1 relationship with an existing disk file. (Without memory mapping, seldom-used ranges of material in RAM could get written-out to a separate swap file to free space for other allocations – which a wasteful operation, and redundant data, when the data already exists on disk somewhere.)

Unfortunately, in the common-case of a single-process, and typical operations like a `most_similar()` which necessarily computes on every single vector, the whole structure will be brought into memory on each `most_similar()`. There's no net RAM "savings" there (though perhaps a slight CPU/IO benefit if other memory pressure would've forced paging-out the loaded ranges). (Whatever approach you're using the sample the "~2.2 GB" and "~1.2 GB" used-RAM values may not be properly measuring that.)

The main benefit is when using multiple processes that each need to consult the same file's data. If naively loaded into RAM, each process will have its own redundant copy of the same data. If using memory-mapping, you've let the OS know: these multiple arrays-in-address-space, in multiple separate processed, definitionally have the same data (as reflected in the file). No matter how many processes need the data, only one copy of each file-range will ever consume RAM. There, a large savings can be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, things are a lot clear now. 

I am calling most_similar(), yes, and it doesn't increase the consumed ram. Are you saying that vectors are loaded into ram, and then discarded, and next time they are loaded again and so on?

One thing I did not understand: 'the "~2.2 GB" and "~1.2 GB" used-RAM values may not be properly measuring that'
How can the OS, not know of the extra ram used, or it is used under some other process (or other way)

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you collected the "~2.2 GB" and "~1.2 GB" values, and if it was just after load or after a full-access (like `most_similar()`). Depending on the exact memory-usage measure/tool you've used, it may be a more or less accurate indicator of the actual RAM used. Yes, they're loaded as needed (when their range of addressable memory is 1st accessed) – but then they stay in RAM until something else needs the RAM more according the OS virtual memory system – at *that* point they may be discarded, and re-loaded upon next access. That's the gist of virtual memory/swapping.

Comment: Under a worst-case scenario – such a mmap'ing a file that's larger than RAM, or lots of other operations using lots of RAM  – then yes, any one sweep through all vectors (as is done by `most_similar()`) could result in every range being both loaded, then unloaded to make room for a later range. But if the mmap'd size, and other dynamic demands on memory, all fit within RAM (and only occasionally overgrow, when shifting between coarse tasks), then modern OS virtual memory is pretty good at keeping the "right" stuff in RAM, and only swapping-out lesser-used regions, to minimize disk-IO.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I understand now.